# Rendering CIImage into OpenGL ES 2.0 texture on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, core-image

Does someone know how to render a CIImage directly into an OpenGL ES 2.0 texture via drawImage:inRect:fromRect: from an EAGL CIContext on iOS?  Rendering via a normal CIContext via createCGImage:fromRect: then loading the image via GLKTextureLoader is too slow for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Wwdc session that covers exactly this. 2012 Session 511 (near the end). Basically what you want to do is:

-Create output texture

-Make output texture the target of a framebuffer

-bind the texture framebuffer as output instead of the screen

-Now use drawImage: inRect: fromRect: to write directly to the texture.